# Storing list into another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to save different list of averages in to a list called
`storage_risk_prem` using the following code:

```
    storage_risk_prem=list(range(len(simul_data)))
    avg_risk_prem=list(range(len(simul_data[0])))
    for i in range(len(simul_data)):
        for j in range(len(avg_risk_prem)):
            avg_risk_prem[j]=np.average(simul_data[i][j])
        ***storage_risk_prem[i]=avg_risk_prem***

    storage=list(range(len(simul_data)))
    w_mean_i=list(range(len(simul_data)))
    w_std_i=list(range(len(simul_data)))
    for i in range(len(w_mean_i)):
        w_mean_i[i]=w.dot(storage_risk_prem[i])
        w_std_i[i]=np.sqrt(w.dot(cal_vcov_sim(simul_data)[i].dot(w)))
        storage[i]=(w_mean_i[i],w_std_i[i])
    return storage
```

However it only stored same lists of averages when I checked for the result (std bit is fine).

So went over my codes and found out that the line in italic caused the problem but I have no idea how to avoid this problem without using `np.vstack`, but I don't want to abuse so many imports to improve my programming.

Comment: If you want a new `avg_risk_prem` list for each `i`, you should of course create it inside the loop. Now you're explicitly setting them all to the same list.

Comment: You can't use italics inside code blocks.

Comment: 'caused the problem' what problem, also what is content of  `simul_data`

Comment: You can do a shallow copy of a list in this way `storage_risk_prem[i]=avg_risk_prem[:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because with your method you add a pointer to your list many times.
You have to copy elements each time for example with list(my_list)

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[list(a), list(a)]
b
=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

a[0] = 10
b
=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```